# Can a method of pedagogy be patented?

Tags: patentability, business-methods

I'm creating a book about how to teach to children. Can I patent the method described in my book?

Comment: General answer: Yes Specific answer: Need more information

Comment: Yes in some countries provided it satisfy patent-ability requirements.

Comment: [Enfish](http://www.ipwatchdog.com/2016/05/13/federal-circuit-says-software-patent-claims-not-abstract-are-patent-eligible/id=69147/) is another case you definitely want to be aware of.  Software implementations of abstract ideas seems to be safe. By contrast, this reinforces the non-patentability of pure methods without technological implementations.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at ["Alice"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_Corp._v._CLS_Bank_International) and ["Bilski"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_Corp._v._CLS_Bank_International) and ["Mayo"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayo_Collaborative_Services_v._Prometheus_Laboratories,_Inc.), the three recent cases that address this area.

Essentially, as I understand it, a purely abstract idea such as a "set of mental steps" is not likely patent eligible at this time.

However, patent law is always in a state of chaos, so you should consult with a patent attorney or two before making any public disclosure, just in case there is a way to render the material eligible. (In March of 2013, US Patent law switched from ["first to invent" to "first to file"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_to_file_and_first_to_invent), thus any public disclosure prior to filing either a provisional or nonprovisional patent will lose you the right to pursue a patent for any disclosed material.)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but depends on the specifics of the method. Talk with a patent attorney to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to patent a method described in your book. But the method has to fulfill that criteria of non-obviousness, novelty and industrial application. Further, there are prior art searches done to establish the above three criteria. on then will your patent be granted.